# Can I invert this function?

Tags: javascript, math

I have the "scaledValue" and I would like to find "Value",

but it seems not possible ? (similar value is accepted)

```
var priceBound = [0, 10000000];
var priceCurves = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 5, 35, 70, 100];

function calcScaledPrice(Value) {
    var currentValue = Value;
    var currentFixed = Value - priceBound[0];

    var fixedBound = priceBound[1] - priceBound[0];

    var currentPercent = Math.round((currentFixed / fixedBound) * 20);
    var currentScale = priceCurves[currentPercent];
    var scaledValue = Math.round(currentValue * (currentScale / 100));

    return scaledValue;
}
```

Comment: Do you want this to be worked around as a equation? or would a console.log(Value) suffice?

Comment: It's invertible if it's a bijection: if it's one-to-one and onto.

Comment: If `scaledValue = currentValue * currentScale / 100` then to solve for *currentValue*: `currentValue = scaledValue * 100 / currentScale`.

Comment: I would like to worked as a equation.


currentValue = scaledValue * 100 / currentScale
but currentScale is an unknow, sorry for my bad mathematics.

Comment: Given that `calcScaledPrice(150) == calcScaledPrice(200) == 2` then he output value is not unique to the input value. Therefore it is impossible to determine the input given the output (the use of *Math.round* gives a hint to that). You can likely determine a range of values for a particular output though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single input value that generates a particular output value so it is impossible to provide a definitive answer. However, it is possible to generate **a** value that will result in a particular scaled value, just that it won't be unique. e.g.

```
calcScaledPrice(150));  // 2
calcScaledPrice(200));  // 2
```

The following generates a series of candidate values, then returns the first that creates a suitable scaled value. Not particularly elegant, but it does the job (only lightly tested so use with caution). There are other iterative approaches, e.g. using a kind of binary search algorithm to find a suitable value.

```
function calcValue(scaledValue) {
    var fixedBound = priceBound[1] - priceBound[0];
    var possibleCurrentValues = [];
    var currentFixed, currentScale, value;

    // Generate a matrix of possible values
    for (var i=0, iLen=priceCurves.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        possibleCurrentValues.push(Math.round(scaledValue * 100 / priceCurves[i]));
    }

    // Return the first possibleCurrentValue that generates
    // a suitable scaled value
    for (var j=0, jLen=possibleCurrentValues.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        value = possibleCurrentValues[j]
/*
        // Do the calculation of calcScaledPrice
        currentFixed = value - priceBound[0];    
        currentPercent = Math.round((currentFixed / fixedBound) * 20);
        currentScale = priceCurves[currentPercent];

        if (Math.round(value * currentScale / 100) == scaledValue) {
            return value;
        }
*/
        // Simpler, depends on calcScaledPrice function
        if (calcScaledPrice(value) == scaledValue) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    return "not found";
}

calcValue(2)  // 200
calcValue(50) // 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program turns the price from a value in range [0..10000000] to an integer in range [0..20], using a linear rule and rounding. Then a (monotonously growing) lookup table returns a percentage to apply to the original value.

What you get is thus a piecewise linear function, which is discontinuous where the percentages change. For instance, values 6249999 and 6250000 will map to percentages 0.01 and 0.012, yielding outputs 62499,99 and 75000. No `scaledValue` between 62499,99 and 75000 does correspond to any `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not a bijection because you map many values in domain to same value due to `Math.round()`. At this point you can still retrieve a range of values for a given scaled value.